# Add raster layers to "raster" tab with python QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, user-interface

I am making a tool in QGIS. I have 3 tabs in the interface tool (Vector, Raster, About). My target is when I work "Vector" tab, all vector layer will add, and if I work "Raster" tab. all raster will add.

At the moment, my script can be add vector layers in "vector" tab, and I have not added raster to "raster" tab.

How can I make to add raster layer to "raster" tab?

**I use this code:**

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # Select the layers open in the legendInterface and add them to an array
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    # Append only Vector (type == 0) to the layer_list

    for layer in layers:
            if layer.type() == 0:
                layer_list.append(layer.name())
```

My tool:

[image]

---

My script in the below that is description add layers vectors to vector Tab, but I tried add vector layers to Raster Tab, still using the same vector tab parameter, but I can't add vectors to Raster TAB.

Could you tell me why and how to add vector to Raster TAB?

This is my full script:

```
from qgis import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter


# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog
from Convertprj_dialog import ConvertprjBatchDialog
import os.path
import os


class ConvertprjBatch:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'ConvertprjBatch_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = ConvertprjBatchDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Convert coordinate system VN2000')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        # self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'BatchSaveLayers')
        # self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'BatchSaveLayers')

        self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
        self.dlg.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output)       


    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('ConvertprjBatch', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=False,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/ConvertprjBatch/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Chuyen he VN2000 Noi bo sang he khac'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # add to plugin toolbar
        self.action1 = QAction(
            QIcon(":/plugins/ConvertprjBatch/icon.png"),
            u"&Convert coordinate system VN2000", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action1)
        self.action1.triggered.connect(self.run)

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Convert coordinate system VN2000'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        # del self.toolbar

        # remove from plugin toolbar
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action1)

    # Select output file 
    def select_output(self):
        output_dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.dlg, "Chọn thư mục để lưu","")
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(output_dir)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Select the layers open in the legendInterface and add them to an array
        layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        layer_list = []
        # Append only Vector (type == 0) to the layer_list

        for layer in layers:
                if layer.type() == 0:
                    layer_list.append(layer.name())     
                elif layer.type() == 1:
                    layer_list.append(layer.name())

        # Add layer_list array to listWidget, clear layer if removed to layer in tools
        self.dlg.listWidget.clear()
        self.dlg.listWidget.addItems(layer_list)
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
```

Comment: In the code snippet you provided, there isn't any information on how you are creating the tabs.